# Java HashMap<Integer, Double> inserts NaN

Tags: java, hashmap, double, nan

I'm trying to save some Double values with an Integer as an Index to a HashMap.
My Problem is that I've got some NaN values in the Map, which is strange, because as you can see in the code below I'm would print out an error if it is NaN.
The println function is never called, even though I got some NaN values in my Map.
The function compareDocs return as Double.

```
    HashMap<Integer, Double> distVec = new HashMap<Integer, Double>();
    int i = 0;
    for (IGSDocument doc : train) {
        Double dist = compareDocs(test, doc);
        if(dist == Double.NaN){
            System.err.println("Not a Number");
        }
        distVec.put(i, dist);
        i++;
    }
    System.out.println(distVec);
```

Does anyone see's my fault?

Comment: NaN is not equal to NaN

Answer (score 3):

`NaN` is not equal to itself (it is not equal to *anything*), so `dist == Double.NaN` is always false. Use

```
if(!dist.isNaN()) {
  distVec.put(i, dist);
  ++i;
}
```

or

```
if(!Double.isNaN(dist)) {
  distVec.put(i, dist);
  ++i;
}
```

the latter also works with `double dist`.

Side note: Since `NaN` is the only number that is not equal to itself,

```
if(dist == dist) {
  ...
}
```

would also work for `double dist` (but is less pretty). I do not suggest that you use it (it doesn't work with the object type `Double`, anyway), but it is illustrative of the mechanism at work.

Comment: I think you mean `!Double.isNaN(dist)`.

Answer (score 1):

Try out [isNan](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#isNaN()) method of Double wrapper class like:

```
dist.isNan()
```

instead of comparing with "==" as NaN is not equal to itself. Also another thing, with your if statement:

```
if(dist == Double.NaN){
     System.err.println("Not a Number");
}
```

Even though with new method usage, you will catch Nan, but that wont again prevent you from entering into hashMap. So you should change your if as:

```
if(dist.isNaN()){
    System.err.println("Not a Number");
    continue;//continue with other values and ignore NaN
}
```